# Image in picture control in MFC dilaog is larger when running applicaiton than is shown in dialog editor

Tags: c++

I am creating a MFC CDialog and adding a bitmap in a picture control and I have edit controls that need to be placed relative to positions on the image. However the size of the image in the picture control changes when I run my application.
This makes it difficult to align my edit boxes with the image.
Can anybody tell me why this happens?
There is no code to post as this is entirely done in the dialog editor of VS2013.

Answer (score 1):

Windows adjusts the size of dialogs to match the system font, which can be changed by the user. For information about this look up dialog base units. If you need your dialog layout to match a bitmap then you need to override the Windows adjustment and explicitly set the size and location of the controls at run time. That would mean that in OnInitDialog you use MoveWindow on the dialog itself and on every control to set their size and location in pixel units that match the bitmap.